# How to make a bar chart with only a height indicator not showing the full bar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

This chart almost looks good but is probably not the way to model this in matplotlib. How to have two horizontal bars that extend to the left and right of vertical line at an x-point to show the change of the two datasets eg SDR from 0.7 to 0.25.

Currently i patch things together with `'$-$'` markers which make misaligned legends and i am not able to place properly. If i change the figsize the markers start misaligning from the vertical bar at their x-point, eg SDR.

How to model this kind of chart proberly?

[image]

```
layer0 = np.random.random(10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(15/2,1.5*2.5),)
ind = np.arange(10, dtype=np.float64)*1#cordx

ax.plot(ind[0::2]+0.05, layer0[0::2]-0.04, ls='None', marker='$-$', markersize=40)
ax.plot(ind[1::2]-0.15, layer0[1::2]-0.04, ls='None', marker='$-$', markersize=40)
ax.set_ylim(0,1.05) 
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, step=0.1))
ax.set_xticks(ind[0::2]+0.5)
ax.set_xticklabels( ('SDR', 'SSR', 'SCR', 'RCR', 'GUR') )
plt.grid(b=True)
plt.grid(color='black', which='major', axis='y', linestyle='--', lw=0.2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use a horizontal bar chart [`barh`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.barh.html) which is more intuitive in this case. Here the key parameter is `left` which will shift your horizontal bar charts to left/right.

Following is a complete answer:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2)
layer0 = np.random.random(10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(15/2,1.5*2.5),)
n = 10
width = 0.5
ind = np.arange(n, dtype=np.float64)*1#cordx

ax.barh(layer0[0::2], [width]*int(n/2), height=0.01, left = ind[0::2])
ax.barh(layer0[1::2], [width]*int(n/2), height=0.01, left = ind[0::2]+width)
ax.set_ylim(0,1.05) 
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, step=0.1))
ax.set_xticks(ind[0::2]+0.5)
ax.set_xticklabels( ('SDR', 'SSR', 'SCR', 'RCR', 'GUR') )
plt.grid(b=True)
plt.grid(color='black', which='major', axis='y', linestyle='--', lw=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

up until now i havent thought of bar charts with bottom offset, which seems to be ok:

```
layer0 = np.random.random(10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(15/1.3,1.5*2.5),)# sharey=True)
ind = np.arange(10, dtype=np.float64)*1#cordx
height=0.03
width=0.8
ax.bar(ind[0::2]-width/2, height, width=width, bottom=layer0[0::2]-height)
ax.bar(ind[0::2]+width/2, height, width=width, bottom=layer0[1::2]-height)
ax.set_ylim(-0.,1.05)
plt.grid(color='black', which='major', axis='x', linestyle='-', lw=0.8)
```

[image]